# How to select distinct date ranges with Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm looking to get distinct rows with a start and end date from a table with structure below. I dont want duplicate rows with same start and end month. Please note that start and end date are NUMBER type here, not date.

```
tbl_app_ranges:
rg_id   start_month   end_month
105     200401        200409    
105     200401        200409    
110     200701        200712    
110     200701        200710
```

What I want is the below result set

```
rg_id   start_month   end_month
105     200401        200409    
110     200701        200712    
110     200701        200710
```

I know this can be done with analytics but not sure how. Is there a way to do this in pure SQL? I need the query to work against Oracle database.

Comment: Use `DISTINCT/UNIQUE` or a `GROUP BY rg_id, start_month, end_month`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select distinct rgid,start_month,end_month from tbl_app_ranges;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `GROUP BY rg_id, start_month, end_month` in your query.

Comment: `DISTINCT` would internally do a `GROUP BY`. +1 for the answer though.

Answer (score 1):

```
select rg_id, start_month, end_month from tbl_app_ranges
group by end_month, start_month, rg_id
```

Comment: No need for the derived table.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT start_month   , end_month 
FROM tbl_app_ranges;
```

SQL DISTINCT clause example would return each unique start month and end month combination.

Answer (score 0):

You asked,

> I know this can be done with analytics but not sure how.

If you want to do it in **Analytics**, then you could use **ROW_NUMBER()** analytic function.

```
select rg_id, start_month, end_month from (
select rg_id,
       start_month,
       end_month,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY rg_id, 
                                      start_month, 
                                      end_month 
                         ORDER BY rg_id) rn        
from tbl_app_ranges)
WHERE rn = 1;
```

**How the query works:**

The `ROW_NUMBER` assigns an ordered row_number to each group as specified in the `PARTITION BY` clause. The sorting is taken care by `ORDER BY` clause. Thsi becomes the inner sub-query, the outer query filters the rows based on the `row_number`.